# SQL SUB SELECTS and LEFT JOINS with WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery

Is it more efficient to leave the WHERE clause out in the 2nd SUB-SELECT. Works both ways but I am looking for most efficient way with this SQL statement...

There are many records and values for substr(FIELD_G,10,3) in table 2 t2 so I am nor sure if I should filter that out in the 2nd SUB-SELECT first before left joining ???

My question is Should I filter the results in the 2nd SUB-SELECT before JOINING or Should I eliminate the WHERE clause (in 2nd SUB-SELECT), Retrieve everything and rely on the LEFTJOIN to give me my results ???

If the CNT equal 0 - I still need the t1.FIELD_A, t1.FIELD_B, t1.FIELD_C, t1.FIELD_D fields to be returned...

```
SELECT t1.FIELD_A, t1.FIELD_B, t1.FIELD_C, t1.FIELD_D, t2.CNT FROM (
    SELECT FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C, FIELD_D
    FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_A
    WHERE FIELD_A IN ('Z1','Z2','Z3','Z4','Z5','Z6','Z7','Z8','Z9','Z10','Z11','Z12','Z13','Z14','Z15','Z16','Z17','Z18','Z19','Z20','Z21','Z22')
              ) t1
    LEFT JOIN
              (
    SELECT FIELD_A, COUNT(FIELD_A) AS CNT FROM (
    SELECT substr(FIELD_G,10,3) AS FIELD_A
    FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_B
    WHERE substr(FIELD_G,10,3) IN ('Z1','Z2','Z3','Z4','Z5','Z6','Z7','Z8','Z9','Z10','Z11','Z12','Z13','Z14','Z15','Z16','Z17','Z18','Z19','Z20','Z21','Z22')
    ) GROUP BY FIELD_A
              ) t2

    ON t1.FIELD_A = t2.FIELD_A
    ORDER BY t1.FIELD_A
  ;
```

Comment: You could always time both queries.

Comment: There's no way that anyone who has no access to your database and its data can state unequivocally that one version of the query will be better or worse. Compare the execution plans of both queries, and (as @DanBracuk suggests) time the execution. Best of luck.

Comment: What do you mean "more efficient"?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get aggregate values in a query with a filter.  The problem is that the aggregations are done over all the data, rather than the filtered subset.  So, your query repeats the criteria.

Another approach is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.FIELD_A, t1.FIELD_B, t1.FIELD_C, t1.FIELD_D,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_B b
        WHERE substr(b.FIELD_G, 10, 3) = t1.FIELD_A
       ) as cnt
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_A t1 LEFT JOIN
WHERE t1.FIELDA IN ('Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'Z5', 'Z6', 'Z7', 'Z8', 'Z9', 'Z10',
                    'Z11', 'Z12', 'Z13', 'Z14', 'Z15', 'Z16', 'Z17', 'Z18', 'Z19', 'Z20',
                   'Z21', 'Z22')
ORDER BY t1.FIELD_A;
```

Comment: Gordon - this does not work - invalid table name near WHERE clause

Comment: Your first paragraph confused me, but I guess it's an analysis of why the OP structured his example query as he did (as opposed to a criticism of his approach).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this Query

```
SELECT t1.FIELD_A, t1.FIELD_B, t1.FIELD_C, t1.FIELD_D, t2.CNT
   FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_A t1
   LEFT JOIN  (
                SELECT FIELD_A, COUNT(FIELD_A) AS CNT FROM (
                SELECT substr(FIELD_G,10,3) AS FIELD_A
                FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_B ) GROUP BY FIELD_A 
    ) t2
    ON t1.FIELD_A = t2.FIELD_A
    WHERE t1.FIELD_A IN ('Z1','Z2','Z3','Z4','Z5','Z6','Z7','Z8','Z9','Z10','Z11','Z12','Z13','Z14','Z15','Z16','Z17','Z18','Z19','Z20','Z21','Z22')
   ORDER BY t1.FIELD_A ;
```